# How can I display Arabic text in fpdf?

Tags: php, arabic, fpdf, html-entities, iconv

I am using fpdf in php for developing pdf. I have to include some static Arabic or Farsi text to this pdf. I had used
    `$farsi_txt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-5', html_entity_decode('حضور محترم'));
 $pdf->Write(5,$farsi_txt);` 

 But the output was Blank.

 When I had displayed it directly 

`$pdf->Write(5,'فغانستان کابل');`

then the out put was like `Ù•ØºØ§Ù†Ø³ØªØ§Ù† Ú©Ø§Ø¨Ù„`

When I had created a window to insert the arabic text to database then the output was  `&#1581;&#1590;&#1608;&#1585; &#1605;&#1581;&#1578;&#1585;&#1605;` 

Is there any way to display this text as Arabic or Farsi in fpdf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arabic script in PDF created by UFPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453728/arabic-script-in-pdf-created-by-ufpdf)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer for my question.
 I had replaced FPDF with TCPDF. 
TCPDF provides special fonts for Arabic and Farsi languages. 
I had got the correct output using TCPDF. 
I simply done this by switching font and 
`$tpdf->setRTL(false);` this sets the right to left alignment if arabic words.
[TCPDF Download link](https://codeload.github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/zip/master)

Answer (score 1):

take a look  [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm). This page specifically talks about adding new Fonts and encodings, which I believe is the issue as the PDF is missing the Arabic font and is unable to find a replacement for characters.